# (Bither) how can i send my bitcoins?

Tags: transactions, wallet, exchanges, block, script

i downloaded Bither as my virtual wallet and added bitcoins in a Hot Wallet Address. But when i try to send bitcoins, i can't. 
i fill the address, the amount of bitcoins and i type my password but the button "send" is colored on light grey and i can't click on it.

So i would like to know how to send bitcoins with Bither, and if i can't, can i switch my wallet to another software ?

Thanks by advance :)